# SELECT statement to check for null values of two columns

Tags: postgresql

I'm running what I think should be a very simple query. All I want to do is select the COUNT of values if one field status is set to Y (for yes) and there is a year entry (i.e.: 1997). I've written the following query and it does not seem to find a result when it should be listed.

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM mydb WHERE status = 'Y' AND year IS NOT NULL
```

It doesn't seem to be picking up when I do have an integer value for my year column. Why is this the case?

Comment: Do you have in the same row with status='Y' AND year IS NOT NULL, it 
should happen simultaneously?

Comment: Yeah I actually figured it out as soon as I posted this, thanks for the feedback though!